# Spring boot, Vaadin - cant autowire Service in a View

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have spring boot application with vaadin and vaadin4spring addon.
In one my View i want to display a data which are in database. Data i want to display are returned by a method in service class.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public List<Users> getUsers() ....
}
```

View:

```
@SpringView(name = Views.USERLIST) //static constant containing string "users"
public class UserlistView extends HorizontalLayout implements View {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @PostConstruct
    public void construct() {
        displaytable(userService.getUsers());
    }
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent) {}

}

UI class:

@SpringUI
@Theme("valo")
public class TUI extends UI {
        @Autowired
        private SpringViewProvider springViewProvider;

        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
          ..
          Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, content);
           navigator.addView(Views.USERLIST, UserlistView.class);
          navigator.addProvider(springViewProvider);

        }
}
```

During the server startup vaadin recognizes the springview - " c.v.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider  : 1 SpringView found", no exceptions or warnings are displayed.

Every time i use navigator display the view (`navigator.navigateTo("users")`) autowired field in the view is not injected and the postprocess method not called. What is even stranger if i dont add the view into the navigator object and use url to access the view directly - localhost:8080/#!users the fields will be injected correctly and method construct() will be called.

If it helps there is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "me.project" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableVaadinEventBus
public class TheConfig {
    // contains only one bean definition - sessionfactory
}
```

Has anyone faced similar problem? I was not able to find help anywhere could anyone please tell me what i did wrong. 
Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have similar problem and the answer from V_J doesn't work.

Comment: Try to add a viewdisplay to the UI, and add your views to the viewdisplay. I had the same problem, but with viewdisplay it solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
navigator.addView(Views.USERLIST, UserlistView.class);
```

It creates a `StaticViewProvider` which is not handled by Spring and creates a view using 'new'. So no spring autowiring happens for 'addView'
If  you use springViewProvider Autowiring is handled by Spring.

So do not do  `navigator.addView()`, instead rely on `springViewProvider` when using Spring+Vaadin.